# Get SWF HTML id attribute (from AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to know the coordinates of the SWF relative to the HTML page. Is there any way to do that?

I was planning on using `ExternalInterface` to call some Javascript code which would return the coordinates, but to do this I would need to know the `id` attribute of the HTML element containing the SWF, How can I get this `id` attribute value from AS3?.

What I didn't want to do is pass the value in `FlashVars`, reason being that I want a library function that I can reuse easily.

Comment: _ExternalInterface.objectID_ is the id of swf object in the DOM

Comment: @fsbmain: Thanks, I didn't even look in this class, I was looking for the id in `loaderinfo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised you found `ExternalInterface`, and not `ExternalInterface.objectID`, which is the ID of the SWF in the page. From that, you can easily get the parent using the js property .parentNode

Please note that objectID return different data depending of the browser :

- IE : the `<object>` id
- Chrome : the `<embed>` id
- Firefox : the `<embed>` id
- Opera : the `<object>` name

Comment: I've used `ExternalInterface` for calling js in the past, but I didn't think the id would be in here, I was looking elsewhere. +1 for the return data for each browser

Comment: What have you guys done where an embed tag does not exist and there is no name attribute?